# jRecorder not showing on page

Tags: html

I'm trying to get a jRecorder embedded on my webpage. I added what it says to add on this doc page http://www.sajithmr.me/jrecorder/index.html, and when I open the page, it is blank.

Page looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script src="jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script src="jRecorder.js"> </script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<script>
    $.jRecorder(
    {
       'rec_width': '300',
       'rec_height': '200',
       'rec_top': '0px',
       'rec_left': '0px',
       'recorderlayout_id' : 'flashrecarea',
       'recorder_id' : 'audiorecorder',
       'recorder_name': 'audiorecorder',
       'wmode' : 'transparent',
       'bgcolor': '#ff0000',
       'swf_path': 'jRecorder.swf',
       'host': 'acceptfile.php?filename=hello.wav',
       'callback_started_recording' : function(){},
       'callback_finished_recording' : function(){},
       'callback_stopped_recording': function(){},
       'callback_error_recording' : function(){},
       'callback_activityTime': function(time){},
       'callback_activityLevel' : function(level){}
        }
        );
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Did I follow this incorrectly?

Comment: I don't use jRecorder, and I don't know what browser your using, but: 1) Make sure it is compatible with your browser & 2) if your browser has an error/debug console, look in it for specific error messages, if any.

Comment: I've used the jRecorder from the same browser on other websites, so I don't think thats the problem.

Answer (score -1):

hey about the jRecorder, 
as Miguel says u need to check the compatibility of your browser.
so if u using chrome or opera or firefox, u won't have any problem with that. 
but if it's IE8 or 9 its not going to work but with IE10 will.
so what u need to do if u want it to work on IE9 u need to modify your jRecorder.js or if u want try to download it from https://github.com/capsula4/jRecorder, i think he solved this.

Thank you